# What's was wrong in my simple code?

Tags: xcode, swift, compiler-errors, runtime-error

```
import UIKit

var b = 3
assert(b <= 0, "this is impossible")
```

and Xcode shows:"exc_bad_instruction (code=exc_i386_invop subcode=0x0)", anyone
 has an idea?!, Is there in my Xcode problem? anyone knows where is the setting playground Optimization Level?

Comment: `assert()` only works in a non-optimized build. Check your `SWIFT_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL` (shows up as `Optimization Level`) in the project settings.

Comment: Where is it, in playground file?

Comment: A playground is different than a project and does not have project settings. I'm not sure how this affects the use of `assert()`. If possible, I would simply avoid using `assert()` unless you absolutely have to.

Comment: I use that because I study "The swift programming" trend to run it, by this, you can check the condition is true or false!

Comment: Look at Ike10's updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On second thought, I think your code is working as it should. Assert should crash your app at runtime if the assertion fails. Check to see if your error message is printed to the console, if so it is working.

Comment: I don't know if you're correct or not, but building off of what you said; asserts are more appropriate within a function that has input parameters rather than  testing single variables.

Comment: @WilliamAnderson changed my answer after a second thought.

Comment: Xcode can says the condition does not compile or like that, No says BAD EXECUTION!

Comment: I believe you're correct @Ike10, after messing around with it in a playground, I found that no issue occurs when the assertion condition is true. `assert()` is a debugging tool that will interrupt execution if the condition is not satisfied.

Comment: @SAt , assert is supposed to prevent your code from running if the assertion fails. So it should stop he process when you press the run button.

Answer (score 0):

```
assert(@autoclosure condition: () -> Bool, @autoclosure _ message: () -> String = default, file: StaticString = #file, line: UInt = #line)
```

> Traditional C-style assert with an optional message.
>   Use this function for internal sanity checks that are active
>   during testing but do not impact performance of shipping code.
>   To check for invalid usage in Release builds; see `precondition`.
>   * In playgrounds and -Onone builds (the default for Xcode's Debug
>     configuration): if `condition` evaluates to false, stop program
>     execution in a debuggable state after printing `message`.
>   * In -O builds (the default for Xcode's Release configuration),
>     `condition` is not evaluated, and there are no effects.
>   * In -Ounchecked builds, `condition` is not evaluated, but the
>     optimizer may assume that it *would* evaluate to `true`. Failure
>     to satisfy that assumption in -Ounchecked builds is a serious
>     programming error.

So your code is working as expected unless your variable `b` assigned dynamically.

```
var b = 3
assert(b <= 0, "this is impossible") //It is expected here to stop the execution 
//since your b is not less than or equal to 0 which results in true and hence 
//`assert` will stop the execution.
```